# Twig strip part of string if true

Tags: symfony, twig

I was wondering if it is possible to strip part(s) of a string when the string contains a word. I've read the doc [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Let's say I have this:

```
<ul>
    {% for category in shop.categories %}
      <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

Outcome of above would be:

<ul>
    <li>Test category 1</li>
    <li>Test category 2</li>
    <li>Testing category 3</li>
</ul>
```

How could you make a if statement that when the word `test` or `testing` is inside `{{ category.title }}` this word is stripped from that title?!

So end result will be `category 1, category 2, category 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twig replace filter is the equivalent of php's str_replace().

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

```
{{ category.title | replace( {'Testing ': '', 'Test ': '' } ) }}
```